# Is there a way to get a reference to an ag-grid object with only a query selector?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

When you instantiate an ag-grid, is there a way to obtain a reference to the object elsewhere in the code via a query selector? I'm trying to achieve something like:

```js
// Script 1
new agGrid.Grid(document.getElementById("myAgGrid"), gridOptions);
```

```js
// Script 2
var gridElement = document.getElementById("myAgGrid");

theAgGrid = gridElement. /* Is there a way to get a ref to the grid here? */;

// do stuff with agGrid
var data = theAgGrid.gridOptions.api.getDataAsCsv();
```

Comment: I hit this problem too. I ended up having to assign the Grid to a global var to use later. I.e. `window.grid = new agGrid.Grid(document.getElementById("myAgGrid"), gridOptions);`

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up setting a property myself on the grid element

At instantiation:

```
var gridElement = document.getElementById("myAgGrid");
var grid = new agGrid.Grid(gridElement, gridOptions);
gridElement.__ag_grid = grid;
```

Later

```
var grid = document.getElementById("myAgGrid").__ag_grid;
```